# NW.js have a "loading" icon while processing request

Tags: javascript, jquery, nw.js

I have an app created with NW?js that works fine.

However, it does a lot of processing (loading, save file, reload it and processing, ...) All of that is done by functions.

While I see that it is doing something (because when I click on the "button" that execute the function, the button remains "clicked" until it is finished), it seems impossible to get a spinner instead.

I have 2 functions that are used to respectively show and hide a spinner, but when I use them at start and end of the function, they are executed almost immediately (normal for show, but not foe hide) and I can't find the reason why

Any idea how I could have a spinner while my function are still processing and hide it when done ?

Thank you

Comment: You are likely to get better answers if you provide code.

Comment: You should really be working with Promise(s) returned from your asynchronous function(s).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions can't "sleep", all the code is executed without any stop, they return immediately. If you want to delay the execution of a function, you need a callback :

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");

button.onclick = function () {
  startSpinning();
  button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  doSomethingTimeConsumingThen(function () {
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
    stopSpinning();
  });
}

function doSomethingTimeConsumingThen (onDone) {
  setTimeout(onDone, 1000);
}

function startSpinning () {
  spinner.innerHTML = "Spinning...";
}

function stopSpinning () {
  spinner.innerHTML = "Not spinning.";
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Do something time consuming</button>
<div id="spinner">Not spinning.</div>
```

A callback is called when something happens, for example when a time consuming task is done. In the above snippet the callback is :

```
function () {
  button.removeAttribute("disabled");
  stopSpinning();
}
```

There must be something similar in your API.